# Any other alternative of react-router-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router, react-router-redux

I want to use `history and location` in action creators (which is a part of redux) but `history and location` are only accessible is routed component, Yes we can pass `history and location` as parameters of function into action creators, but that makes code very totally dependent to `history and location` because one action creators is using other action creators internally somewhere.

I am using `react-router-redux`, as i am updating **react-router-dom** to latest version i.e **5.2.0**, which is not supporting `react-router-redux`, Is their any other alternative to `react-router-redux` so i can access `history and location` is any action creators easily.